# Total Reputation: Users vs. Changed

Tags: discussion, reputation-leagues

Is it just me or does this seem a little weird?

[image: screenshot of rep]

The Users list and Change list are equal in the all time tab at StackExchange.
Is this intended? I can imagine its use on other timeframes but here it seems not needed.

Comment: While it's logically correct, the "Change" column doesn't need to be displayed in the "All Time" case. However, I suspect the effort needed to fix it is disproportionate to the severity of the problem.

Comment: That would be the only *correct* info. What's the problem?

Comment: There is no problem just info that doesn't need to be displayed.

Comment: I actually think it's more clear for it to be there, for consistency with the other time frames. Those numbers equalling-up as they do is a nice, sound verification that yes - the 'changed' info is correct. It's a tiny thing, I know :)

Answer (score 2):

*Change* column is not displayed any more in the **Total Reputation** table. There is now a separate table which displays data related to **Reputation Change**.

Screenshot of the [User Reputation Leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow):

[image: Total Reputation table]

[image: Reputation Change table]